# why php_pthreads canot use for to created multithreading ? PHP 5.3 with php_pthreads extendsion

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

```
<?php

class Timer {
    static private  $s;
    function __construct()
    {
        self::$s = self::getmicrotime();
    }

    static public  function Start()
    {
        self::$s = self::getmicrotime();
    }

    static public function Fetch($decimalPlaces = 6)
    {
        return number_format((self::getmicrotime() - self::$s), $decimalPlaces);
    }
    static public function getmicrotime()
    {
        return array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
    }

}

class T extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        test();
    }
}


function test()
{
    $n = 0;
    for($i=1;$i<9999999;$i++)
    {
        $n+=$i;
    }
    echo '#';
}


//+++++++++++++++++++++++START DEMO ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Timer::Start(); 

    //DEMO1,TIME:3.679208 second(s). 

    $ts = array();
    while (count($ts)<10) {
        $t = new T();
        $t->start();
        $ts[]=$t;
    }
    $ts = array(); 

    //DEMO2,TIME:6.876037 second(s). 
    /* for($k=0;$k<10;$k++)
    {
        $t = new T();
        $t->start();
    } */


    echo '<br />Processed in '.Timer::Fetch().' second(s).'; 
?>
```

I am reading http://pthreads.org/ on the topic of pthreads and i have this questions,I want to test php multithreading ,but when i use for to create  multithreading,but it is not the result I want.

In fact the DEMO1 is correct.

But why the second DEMO elapsed_time 6.876037 second ?

**DEMO2 why canot use for to create  multithreading ?**

Comment: The second loop forcibly joins $t on each iteration, because you are re-using the variable; it must.